# Setting up selenium webdriver for parallel execution

Tags: selenium, testing, specflow, xunit

I am trying to execute a large suite of selenium tests via xUnit console runner in parallel.

These have executed and I see 3 chrome windows open, however the first send key commands simply executes 3 times to one window, resulting in test failure.

I have registered my driver in an objectcontainer before each scenario as below:

```
[Binding]
public class WebDriverSupport
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

    public WebDriverSupport(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void InitializeWebDriver()
    {
        var driver = GetWebDriverFromAppConfig();                       
        _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(driver);
    }
```

And then call the driver in my specflow step defintions as:

```
_driver =   (IWebDriver)ScenarioContext.Current.GetBindingInstance(typeof(IWebDriver));
            ScenarioContext.Current.Add("Driver", _driver);
```

However this has made no difference and it seems as if my tests are trying to execute all commands to one driver.

Can anyone advise where I have gone wrong ?

Comment: maybe seeing the contents of `GetWebDriverFromAppConfig();` would be useful as this is where you actually create the web driver instance, presumably

Comment: Hi, this is just a method that returns a driver based on an entry in the app.config. In this instance its a chrome driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `ScenarioContext.Current` in a parallel execution context. If you're injecting the driver through `_objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs` you will receive it through constructor injection in your steps class' constructor, like so:

```
public MyScenarioSteps(IWebDriver driver)
{
    _driver = driver;
}
```

More info:

- https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Parallel-Execution#thread-safe-scenariocontext-featurecontext-and-scenariostepcontext
- https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Context-Injection

In my opinion this is horribly messy.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer, but is too big for a comment.

why are you using the `IObjectContainer` if you are just getting it from the current scenario context and not injecting it via the DI mechanism? I would try this:

```
[Binding]
public class WebDriverSupport
{
    [BeforeScenario]
    public void InitializeWebDriver()
    {
        var driver = GetWebDriverFromAppConfig();                       
        ScenarioContext.Current.Add("Driver",driver);
    }
}
```

then in your steps:

```
_driver =   (IWebDriver)ScenarioContext.Current.Get("Driver");
```

As long as `GetWebDriverFromAppConfig` returns a new instance you should be ok...